# Best way to cast a VIEW row type to the underlying TABLE row type

Tags: postgresql, view, cast, row, composite-types

I have a table with an index and a row-level security policy. Due to [this problem](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/232789/188406) (more details: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48230535/1048572), [2](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/2811772.0XtDgEdalL@peanuts2), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63008838/1048572), [4](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAGrP7a2t+JbeuxpQY+RSvNe4fr3+==UmyimwV0GCD+wcrSSb=w@mail.gmail.com), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48230535/1048572)), the index is not used when the policy applies, which makes my queries unbearably slow.

The workaround I am contemplating would be to create a `VIEW` with `security_invoker = false` and `security_barrier = false`. (If I do enable the `security_barrier`, the query again doesn't use the index).

The problem I am facing now is that I cannot just change the queries to use `FROM my_view AS example` instead of `FROM my_table AS example`, since some of them use functions that are defined to take the `my_table` composite type. A simplified example:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  id int,
  name text,
  is_visible boolean
);
CREATE VIEW test AS SELECT * FROM example WHERE is_visible;
CREATE FUNCTION prop(e example) RETURNS text LANGUAGE SQL AS $$ SELECT e.id::text || ': ' || e.name; $$;

SELECT e.prop FROM example e; -- works
SELECT e.prop FROM test e;    -- ERROR:  column e.prop does not exist
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/cb0bn3NV))</sup>

Now the question is **how to cast the rows to the expected type?** There is [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/247240/188406) and I also found a way to do this using the `ROW` constructor, but I'm not certain how good this is:

```
SELECT e.prop FROM (SELECT (ROW(test.*)::example).* FROM test) e;
```

It's nice that I can just use it as a drop-in replacement for the table expression (without changing anything else in the query), and it does work (postgres accepts it and does use my index when I have the respective `WHERE` clause), but it looks horrible. Are there problems with my approach that I am missing? Is there a better solution?

Comment: Why don't you just include it into the view definition itself?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you mean `SELECT *, example.prop`? I'm not using the function in all queries that depend on the view, and it's not just one function but many. I wouldn't want to update the view if I were to create a new function. (Also this doesn't work with functions taking multiple parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You can use two casts via `text`:

```
SELECT prop(e::text::example) FROM test e;
```

Your idea with the row constructor also works, and it is a better solution. You can easily verify that with `EXPLAIN (VERBOSE)`:

```
EXPLAIN (VERBOSE, COSTS OFF) SELECT test::text::example FROM test;

                    QUERY PLAN                          
══════════════════════════════════════════════════
 Seq Scan on laurenz.test
   Output: ((ROW(test.a, test.b))::text)::example
 Query Identifier: 1322302112480528651
(3 rows)

EXPLAIN (VERBOSE, COSTS OFF) SELECT ROW(test.*)::example FROM test;

               QUERY PLAN                          
════════════════════════════════════════
 Seq Scan on laurenz.test
   Output: ROW(test.a, test.b)::example
 Query Identifier: 3255314901775380938
(3 rows)
```

The latter version has one type cast less.

But the whole setup seems wrong. If you want to bypass row level security, create a role with `BYPASSRLS` or create a special “empty” policy. Another solution might be a `SECURITY DEFINER` function owned by the table owner.

But then, if you bypass row level security, hacky or clean, why do you have it at all?

Comment: I'm not really trying to bypass the security policy, the view has a `WHERE` condition with the same rule as the policy. I really like to generally have the rls policy when interacting with the table normally, it's just there is a few queries that need to use the index so I was going to change these to select from the view instead.

Comment: Is converting to `text` and back really better? I thought `prop(ROW(e.*)::example)` would be optimised away as a no-op since the binary representation would be identical.

Comment: I tried to answer that question in my extended answer.